# Is there a fast tool to show all the unique unicode characters in a file and their count?

Tags: python, unicode, coreutils

Does anybody know a tool to tabulate all the unique unicode characters and their counts in a file?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly with "unicode characters". To count the different characters in a file you could do something like this:

```
$ awk -v FS="" -v OFS="\t" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) char[$i]++} END { for(i in char) print i,char[i]}' input.txt
```

With `-v FS=""` we set the field separator to nothing. So each character is handled as a single field. In each line we iterate over these fields using the character as a key for the list and increment the count with `++`. If all lines were read, we iterate over the counting list and print each key (which represents the character) and its count.

Comment: Note that this is going to be locale-dependent (and there are certainly conceptions of "unicode character" that it doesn't satisfy, as you noted).